# scheduled job for backing up reporting services encryption key

Tags: reporting-services

I want to backup reporting services encryption key daily using SQl server agent job. I will be using the following syntax

```
rskeymgmt -e -i <> -f <> -p<password>
```

but when run on cmd it prompts me "are you sure you want to extract encryption key from report server". Only after typing "y" and pressing enter it lets me finish the task.
When we backup encryption keys using "Report services configuration" GUI, it doesnt ask such question.

How can I prevent it from prompting using cmd?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution from one of my friends:

Put <\RESPONSE at the end of the RsKeymgmt command and in the RESPONSE file put the letter Y. RESPONSE was placed in C drive.

[Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/2273a27f-9b40-4dd1-ab6e-1861914d2b86)